# What is a simple, effective way to debug custom Kafka connectors?

Tags: java, debugging, apache-kafka, slf4j, apache-kafka-connect

I'm working a couple of Kafka connectors and I don't see any errors in their creation/deployment in the console output, however I am not getting the result that I'm looking for (no results whatsoever for that matter, desired or otherwise). I made these connectors based on Kafka's example FileStream connectors, so my debug technique was based off the use of the SLF4J Logger that is used in the example. I've searched for the log messages that I thought would be produced in the console output, but to no avail. Am I looking in the wrong place for these messages? Or perhaps is there a better way of going about debugging these connectors?

Example uses of the SLF4J Logger that I referenced for my implementation:

[Kafka FileStreamSinkTask](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/198a43d84693153c0f0177b8314117525c05047b/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSinkTask.java)

[Kafka FileStreamSourceTask](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/198a43d84693153c0f0177b8314117525c05047b/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSourceTask.java)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I will try to reply to your question in a broad way. A simple way to do Connector development could be as follows:

- Structure and build your connector source code by looking at one of the many Kafka Connectors available publicly (you'll find an extensive list available here: https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/ )
- Download the latest Confluent Open Source edition (>= 3.3.0) from https://www.confluent.io/download/
- Make your connector package available to Kafka Connect in one of the following ways:

  1. Store all your connector jar files (connector jar plus dependency jars excluding Connect API jars) to a location in your filesystem and enable plugin isolation by adding this location to the 
     `plugin.path` property in the Connect worker properties. For instance, if your connector jars are stored in `/opt/connectors/my-first-connector`, you will set `plugin.path=/opt/connectors` in your worker's properties (see below).
  2. Store all your connector jar files in a folder under `${CONFLUENT_HOME}/share/java`. For example: `${CONFLUENT_HOME}/share/java/kafka-connect-my-first-connector`. (Needs to start with `kafka-connect-` prefix to be picked up by the startup scripts). $CONFLUENT_HOME is where you've installed Confluent Platform.
- Optionally, increase your logging by changing the log level for Connect in `${CONFLUENT_HOME}/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties` to `DEBUG` or even `TRACE`.
- Use Confluent CLI to start all the services, including Kafka Connect. Details here: http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html

  Briefly: `confluent start`

> Note: The Connect worker's properties file currently loaded by the CLI is `${CONFLUENT_HOME}/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties`. That's the file you should edit if you choose to enable classloading isolation but also if you need to change your Connect worker's properties.

- Once you have Connect worker running, start your connector by running:

  `confluent load <connector_name> -d <connector_config.properties>`

  or

  `confluent load <connector_name> -d <connector_config.json>`

  The connector configuration can be either in java properties or JSON format.
- Run
  `confluent log connect` to open the Connect worker's log file, or navigate directly to where your logs and data are stored by running

  `cd "$( confluent current )"`

> Note: change where your logs and data are stored during a session of the Confluent CLI by setting the environment variable `CONFLUENT_CURRENT` appropriately. E.g. given that `/opt/confluent` exists and is where you want to store your data, run:
>
> `export CONFLUENT_CURRENT=/opt/confluent`
>   `confluent current`

- Finally, to interactively debug your connector a possible way is to apply the following before starting Connect with Confluent CLI :

  `confluent stop connect`
  `export CONNECT_DEBUG=y; export DEBUG_SUSPEND_FLAG=y;`
  `confluent start connect`

  and then connect with your debugger (for instance remotely to the Connect worker (default port: 5005). To stop running connect in debug mode, just run: `unset CONNECT_DEBUG; unset DEBUG_SUSPEND_FLAG;` when you are done.

I hope the above will make your connector development easier and ... more fun!

Comment: Hey @Konstantine Karantasis, thank you for the answer. I've gotten a chance to try out Confluent, but I've found myself stuck at trying to load my connectors, is there anymore detail you could provide on the step? My connectors are packaged as such in a jar in the location you instructed: neo4k.filestream.source.Neo4jFileStreamSourceConnector and neo4k.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector; and have the following config files respectively located at ${CONFLUENT_HOME}/etc/kafka-connect-neo4j: connect-neo4j-file-source.properties and connect-neo4j-sink.properties.

Comment: Never mind, I got the load command to find the .properties file. It was just a matter of correct filepathing.

Comment: `export KAFKA_DEBUG=y;`  
Setting KAFKA_DEBUG worked for me instead of CONNECT_DEBUG.

Answer (score 1):

i love the accepted answer.  one thing - the environment variables didn't work for me...  i'm using confluent community edition 5.3.1...

here's what i did that worked...

i installed the confluent cli from here:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/installing.html#tarball-installation

i ran confluent using the command `confluent local start`

i got the connect app details using the command `ps -ef | grep connect`

i copied the resulting command to an editor and added the arg (right after java):

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

then i stopped connect using the command `confluent local stop connect`

then i ran the connect command with the arg

brief intermission ---

> vs code development is led by erich gamma - of `gang of four` fame, who also wrote eclipse.  vs code is becoming a first class java ide  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Gamma

intermission over ---

next i launched vs code and opened the debezium oracle connector folder (cloned from here) https://github.com/debezium/debezium-incubator

then i chose `Debug - Open Configurations`

[image]

and entered the highlighted debugging configuration

[image]

and then run the debugger - it will hit your breakpoints !!

[image]

the connect command should look something like this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -Xms256M -Xmx2G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/folders/yn/4k6t1qzn5kg3zwgbnf9qq_v40000gn/T/confluent.CYZjfRLm/connect/logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/Users/myuserid/confluent-5.3.1/bin/../etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties -cp /Users/myuserid/confluent-5.3.1/share/java/kafka/*:/Users/myuserid/confluent-5.3.1/share/java/confluent-common/*:/Users/myuserid/confluent-5.3.1/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/*:/Users/myuserid/confluent-5.3.1/bin/../share/java/kafka/*:/Users/myuserid/confluent-5.3.1/bin/../support-metrics-client/build/dependant-libs-2.12.8/*:/Users/myuserid/confluent-5.3.1/bin/../support-metrics-client/build/libs/*:/usr/share/java/support-metrics-client/* org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed /var/folders/yn/4k6t1qzn5kg3zwgbnf9qq_v40000gn/T/confluent.CYZjfRLm/connect/connect.properties
```

Comment: Environment variable should work but it's KAFKA_DEBUG https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L220

Answer (score 1):

Connector module is executed by the kafka connector framework. For debugging, we can use the standalone mode. we can configure IDE to use the ConnectStandalone main function as entry point.

1. create debug configure as the following. Need remember to tick "Include dependencies with "Provided" scope if it is maven project 
   [image]
2. connector properties file need specify the connector class name "connector.class" for debugging 
   [image]
3. worker properties file can copied from kafka folder /usr/local/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the kafka startup scripts led me this command line:

```
KAFKA_DEBUG=1 DEBUG_SUSPEND_FLAG=y bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/my-connector.properties
```

The `KAFKA_DEBUG` and `DEBUG_SUSPEND_FLAG` env vars were enough to get the JVM to pause on start and allow me to connect from IntelliJ.

The version of IntelliJ I'm using found the process and offered it in list so I didn't need to configure anything.