# Kafka Connect in debug mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using native apache kafka and not confluent's edition of kafka.

I am using using kafka jdbc connector pluggin. I intend to put a break point and inspect through my IDE (intelliJ).

How to make connect listen on a debug port and suspend. I referred [What is a simple, effective way to debug custom Kafka connectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717658/what-is-a-simple-effective-way-to-debug-custom-kafka-connectors) but that's for confluent kafka

I am looking for below confluent configuration equivalents for apache kafka

```
CONNECT_DEBUG=y; export DEBUG_SUSPEND_FLAG=y;
```

Answer (score 1):

> confluent's edition of kafka

There is no such thing. Both are the same Apache Kafka, so the scripts are the same (which is `kafka-run-class`)

What you reference, the `confluent` CLI command, is intended for local deployments of the Confluent stack, just redirects `CONNECT_DEBUG` into `KAFKA_DEBUG`

Therefore, it is always `KAFKA_DEBUG` for all Kafka Components (including Zookeeper, surprisingly) not `CONNECT_DEBUG` specifically for Connect.