# Kafka Producer vs Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to push data from database(say Oracle DB)  to a kafka topic by calling a stored procedure.I need to do some validations too on message

Should i use a Producer API or Kafka Connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Kafka Connect. Either that, or use the producer API and write some code that handles:

- Scale-out
- Failover
- Restarts
- Schemas
- Serialisation
- Transformations

and that integrates with hundreds of other technologies in a standardised manner for ease of portability and management.

At which point, you'll have reinvented Kafka Connect ;-)

To learn more about Kafka Connect see [this talk](http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect). To learn about the specifics of database->Kafka ingestion see [this talk](http://rmoff.dev/ksny19-no-more-silos) and [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc).

Comment: Thanks a lot .I have written the code .but i think it makes more sense to use Kafka Connect.No point in re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I agree :) Please remember to mark the question as answered if it is.

Comment: MoffattJust one question is begugging connector hard ?As mentioned here in this article
`https://medium.com/@stephane.maarek/the-kafka-api-battle-producer-vs-consumer-vs-kafka-connect-vs-kafka-streams-vs-ksql-ef584274c1e`

Comment: @amitjain please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45717658/7109598 about debugging