# how to setup kafka connect in intellij IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to setup kafka connect in Intellij IDE so that I can understand how it works especially the way it loads the jar files in the plugin path and how it calls the methods present in the jar so that I can develop solutions on top of that. I have searched for docs but I am not able find any good guide that explains on this. please help me by providing any information available for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would clone Kafka source code

Then you can set breakpoints in the connect module, and attach a remote debugger to a running Connect JVM

[What is a simple, effective way to debug custom Kafka connectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717658/what-is-a-simple-effective-way-to-debug-custom-kafka-connectors)

Comment: based on the post in the link 
export CONNECT_DEBUG=y; export DEBUG_SUSPEND_FLAG=y;
should I add those two as ENV variables since I am suing docker compose to run kafka connect ?

Comment: You can, yes. But it would be `KAFKA_DEBUG` instead of `CONNECT_DEBUG`