# Kafka mqtt connector error in stand alone mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mosquitto

I have an MQTT broker and Kafka broker running on ubuntu. I can publish messages to Kafka console consumers through producers. However, when I try to publish a message on Kafka through connector by this repository https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/kafka-mqtt-source-connector in standalone mode, this throws the following error:

[image: error at sintef] .

These are the configuration for

1. connect-standalone.properties file:

[image: connect-standalone.properties]

2. source connector.properties file:

[image: mqtt-kakfa-connector]

Please help me in connecting mosquitto to Kafka.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are hard to read and impossible for users of screen readers. Post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that this dependendency declared in the POM is not part of the JAR that you've put in the plugin path

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Looking at the logs, it seems to have used the `SNAPSHOT` jar file, not the `with-dependencies` one

Comment: I tried adding jar file _with-dependencies_ and then restarted both brokers. When the command _mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1883 -t test -m "Hey" _, it give me an error at MQTTSourceConnectorTask.                                                                                            **ERROR MqttSourceConnectorTask org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JsonReader was expecting a value but found 'hey' **

Comment: Error seems self-descriptive. You sent `-m "Hey"`, but you have `value.converter` expecting JSON, not plain strings. For example, try `-m '{"msg":"Hey"}'`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your timely response. I tried this too but it gives me same error. Any advice what I am missing ?

Comment: I don't think you should get the exact same error containing `but found 'hey'` in that case. I have no experience with this connector to really answer further. If changing to StringConverter doesn't work, then I suggest opening a github issue or trying to [set up a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717658/what-is-a-simple-effective-way-to-debug-custom-kafka-connectors) with the source code

Comment: And if you did look at the github issues, you'd notice at least one person says it doesn't work, and looking at the source code, I definitely agree with them. Specifically, you're not sending data with at least 21 `/` characters to split on... I suggest finding a different connector such as the Confluent one, or https://github.com/johanvandevenne/kafka-connect-mqtt

Comment: I tried evokly connector as I had to use in standalone mode. Thanks for the reply.