# Kafka Connect Sink running but only with empty sinkRecords

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a KafkaConnect service running, to which I am able to add a connector via it's REST interface (POST `/connectors`).
The request body looks like this (simplified):

```
{
  "name": "my-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.streamprocessing.MySinkConnector",
    "topics.regex": "MyComponent\\.MyTopic.*"   //should listen to everything with Prefix "MyComponent.MyTopic"
  }
}
```

A subsequent GET request to `/connectors?expand=info&expand=status` then correctly returns me the connector with its task (id 0), both having the state `RUNNING`.

The task is being executed, but my custom code inside the Task classes' `put()` is never executed, because the `sinkRecords` Collection from its signature is always empty and therefore triggers an early return:

```
public class MySinkTask extends SinkTask {
@Override
public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> sinkRecords) {
   log.info("Start put, batch size: " + sinkRecords.size());
   int batchSize = sinkRecords.size();

   if (batchSize == 0) {
       return;
   }
   // ...
}
```

This keeps logging me a size of 0 every 10 seconds, I already tested with two different Kafka brokers and verified the reception of my test messages by consuming them separately in both cases.

Possible problem sources which - I am sure - can be excluded:

- Connection to Kafka broker (topics for config, status and offsets are created successfully -> at least the initial connection is established successfully)
- Wrong configuration of the connector -> put() function is called successfully and returns because the early return condition is truthy
- Invalid topic in request body -> I tried with different variations of the regex in `topics.regex`  (including matching everything via `".*"`) as well as the specific topic (in `topics`, which should also work according to [the documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/connect/sink-connect-configs.html#topics)

I also tried deploying my source code to our test environment to see if it works there, but that results in the exact same behavior as to when I run everything locally.
The sink is supposed to consume messages produced with a specific topic prefix and insert them into a new MongoDB collection.

I do not have any more ideas for what could cause the `sinkRecords` to be empty, did anybody ever have this issue?

Comment: Connectors, like any consumer, default to set auto.offset.reset=latest, so are you producing new records **after** starting the connector? Or have you tried overriding that config?

Comment: I did not override that config, but always produced new messages after setting it all up

Comment: Not sure, then. You may want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717658/what-is-a-simple-effective-way-to-debug-custom-kafka-connectors